# Volver a la opción anterior

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buenas Tardes a todos...
tengo una "Confusion" al momento de volver a la opcion anterior.

```
if userInput.lower() == "s":

    respuesta = input("Respecto a: (1)Interfaz?  (2)Metodos?  (3)Funciones? (4)misceláneos?  ")

    while respuesta == "1":
        DetalleRespuesta = input("para interfaz tenemos (1)Teclado y (2)Mouse,*(3)Volver*, Cual de ellos le iteresa?: ")
        while DetalleRespuesta == "1":
            Funciones.AbrirWord(), time.sleep(10)
            TecladoPyAutoGui.ComandosTeclado()
        if DetalleRespuesta == "2":
            Funciones.AbrirWord(), time.sleep(10)
            MousePyAutoGui.ComandosMouse()
```

El problema radica en que no logro salir con la opción *3* y volver a 
`respuesta = input("Respecto a: (1)Interfaz?  (2)Metodos?  (3)Funciones? (4)misceláneos?  ")`.

Comment: Pareciera que el problema es que `respuesta` siempre vale "1".

Comment: Hola Franco, se entiende lo que quieres hacer, pero desde donde quieres volver y bajo que condición?. Tienes que romper los dos `while` cambiando el valor de `respuesta` y `detallerespuesta` en principio. Intenta explicar un poco cual debería ser el flujo del programa.

Comment: Primero Gracias por tu respuesta @FJSevilla lo que intento es ingresar en una duda con Interfaz, Metodos, Funciones, Miscelaneos, al entrar en la opción de interfaz, dar opción Teclado, Mouse o volver, si el usuario presiona el numero 3 deberá volver a la opción Respuesta. para poder entrar a otro menú como Métodos. etc...
es decir... si el usuario presiona el Numero 3 volver a la opcion anterior.

Comment: Vale, y ¿bajo qué condición sales del segundo `while` si `Detallerespuesta` es 1? Ese ciclo no se romperá si dentro de el no cambias el valor de `Detallerespuesta` o usas `break`. ¿Por que usas un `While` en la primera condición y un `if` en la segunda?

Comment: cuando el usuario presiona el numero 3

        elif DetalleRespuesta=="3":
            print("La Duda NO es Sobre interfaz entonces, Favor elegir una de las opciones anteriores ")

lo intente tambien cambiando el "while" por un "if"
pero el resultado es el mismo. en resumen eso es lo que me gustaria saber :D..
bajo que condicion salgo del segundo while y "retrocedo" al paso anterior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si usas un ciclo `while` va a estar iterando hasta que no modifiques la variable de control o uses una sentencia `break` para romperlo. Con el código que muestras, en ningún momento llegas a romper ninguno de los dos `while`.

Tu código debería ser algo así (se han sustituido las funciones por simples prints para poder reproducir el código):

```
if userInput.lower() == "s":

    while True:
        respuesta = input("Respecto a: (1)Interfaz?  (2)Metodos?  (3)Funciones? (4)misceláneos (5)Volver?  ")

        if respuesta == "1":
            while True:
                DetalleRespuesta = input("para interfaz tenemos (1)Teclado y (2)Mouse,*(3)Volver*, Cual de ellos le iteresa?: ")

                if DetalleRespuesta == "1":
                    print("Teclado")

                elif DetalleRespuesta == "2":    
                    print("Mouse")

                elif DetalleRespuesta == "3":
                    break  # Salimos de insterfaz

                else:
                    print("Opción inválida")

        elif respuesta == "2":
            print("Métodos")

        elif respuesta == "3":
            print("Funciones")

        elif respuesta == "4":
            print("Misceláneos")

        elif respuesta == "5":
            break # Salimos de la opción "s"

        else:
            print("Opción inválida")
```

Cuando las condiciones son excluyentes no uses `if` encadenados, esto es ineficiente porque si se entra en el primero, todos los demás serán evaluados después igualmente. Usa `elif` en su lugar, si se entra en una de las condicionas el resto no se comprueban directamente.

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias @FJSevilla , El codigo Funciona perfectamente. 
Modifique algunas cosas...
veo la forma de poder dejar el codigo Funcional aqui.

Answer (score 0):

A ver.. Estas usando varios `while <condicion>` eso es un bloque de código que se repetirá hasta que `<condicion>` deje de cumplirse. Por ejemplo, en este bloque

```
        DetalleRespuesta = input("para interfaz tenemos (1)Teclado y (2)Mouse,*(3)Volver*, Cual de ellos le iteresa?: ")
        while DetalleRespuesta == "1":
            Funciones.AbrirWord(), time.sleep(10)
            TecladoPyAutoGui.ComandosTeclado()
```

Si el usuario ingresa `1` las siguientes dos instrucciones se ejecutarán por siempre, ya que nunca modificas el valor de `DetalleRespuesta` que rompería la condición `while DetalleRespuesta == "1":`. Con el `while` anterior pareciera que ocurre lo mismo, pero en este caso lo que no cambia es `respuesta`.

Voy a reescribir un poco tu código para que entiendas conceptualmente el tema y lo puedas aplicar.

En primer lugar tenemos un bloque de ejecución repetitivo con las opciones `(1)Interfaz?  (2)Metodos?  (3)Funciones? (4)misceláneos (5)Salir?`, nota que agregué una opción `5` para finalizar el ciclo, la condición del `while` es ejecutarse mientras el usuario no haya ingresado la opción de "salir". Dentro de este ciclo cuando seleccionan la opción `1`, entramos a un "submeno" con las opciones `(1)Teclado y (2)Mouse,*(3)Volver*` y el procedimiento es el mismo, hacemos un ciclo mientras no se cumpla la condición de volver/salir. Dentro de cada ciclo debemos volver a preguntar al usuario las opciones que desea, ya que es la única forma de "romper" cada `while`: volver a pedir el dato que maneja el ciclo (`respuesta` o `DetalleRespuesta`)

```
respuesta = input("Respecto a: (1)Interfaz?  (2)Metodos?  (3)Funciones? (4)misceláneos (5)Salir?  ")
while respuesta != "5":

    # Interfaz
    if respuesta == "1":

       DetalleRespuesta = input("para interfaz tenemos (1)Teclado y (2)Mouse,*(3)Volver*, Cual de ellos le iteresa?: ")
       while DetalleRespuesta != "3":

         if DetalleRespuesta == "1":
            pass

         elif DetalleRespuesta == "2":
            pass

         DetalleRespuesta = input("para interfaz tenemos (1)Teclado y (2)Mouse,*(3)Volver*, Cual de ellos le iteresa?: ")

    # Metodos
    elif respuesta == "2":
       pass

    # Funciones
    elif respuesta == "3":
       pass

    # Volvemos a preguntar 
    respuesta = input("Respecto a: (1)Interfaz?  (2)Metodos?  (3)Funciones? (4)misceláneos (5)Salir?  ")
```

Una variante de este mismo código, para evitar tener que escribir dos veces la instrucción de `input`de las opciones, es inicializar las variable con algún valor que permita entrar a cada ciclo:

```
respuesta = ""
while respuesta != "5":

    respuesta = input("Respecto a: (1)Interfaz?  (2)Metodos?  (3)Funciones? (4)misceláneos (5)Salir?  ")

    # Interfaz
    if respuesta == "1":

       DetalleRespuesta = ""    
       while DetalleRespuesta != "3":

         DetalleRespuesta = input("para interfaz tenemos (1)Teclado y (2)Mouse,*(3)Volver*, Cual de ellos le iteresa?: ")
         if DetalleRespuesta == "1":
            pass

         elif DetalleRespuesta == "2":
            pass

    # Metodos
    elif respuesta == "2":
       pass

    # Funciones
    elif respuesta == "3":
       pass
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu ayuda @pmoracho 

:)

Answer (score 0):

Estimados.
Gracias por sus respuestas.
El **Codigo** Funcional quedo de esta forma 
`nombre = input("Por favor ingrese su nombre: ")`
`print("Buenas {} {}".format(tiempo(), nombre))`
`userInput = ""`
`while userInput.lower() not in {'s', 'n'}:`
    `userInput = input("¿Tiene Alguna Duda? S/N: ")`
    `if userInput.lower() not in {'s', 'n'}:`
        `print('Respuestas Posibles S, N')`
    `elif userInput.lower() == "n":`
        `print("Buena {} {}".format(tiempo(), nombre))`

`if userInput.lower() == "s":`
    `while True:`
        `respuesta = input("Respecto a: (1)Interfaz?  (2)Metodos?  (3)Funciones?  (4)misceláneos? (5)Volver??  ")`
        `if respuesta == "1":`
            `DetalleRespuesta = input("para interfaz tenemos (1)Teclado y (2)Mouse,(3)Volver, Cual de ellos le iteresa?: ")`
        `if DetalleRespuesta == "1":`
            `Funciones.AbrirWord(), time.sleep(10)`
            `TecladoPyAutoGui.ComandosTeclado()`
        `elif DetalleRespuesta == "2":`
            `Funciones.AbrirWord(), time.sleep(10)`
           `MousePyAutoGui.ComandosMouse(), time.sleep(10)`
            `Funciones.CerrarWord()`
       `else:` #siendo este ultimo quien me saca del ciclo anterior

```
        `print("La Duda NO es Sobre interfaz entonces..."),time.sleep(2) `       

        `print("Intente nuevamente por favor")`
```

Nuevamente Doy Las Gracias a quienes se tomaron el tiempo de ayudar.